# Want to make a Search Engine

Tags: search-engine, bittorrent

I want to make a torrent search engine which will provide links to other torrent sites. So I need data from other sites to index them in the database. So, is it legal to crawl a website for this purpose or is there some other way to do that.

Comment: Unless they have a `robots.txt`, you'd more or less be doing what every search engine does. Either way, legal matter, consult a lawyer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a legal matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the site, without permission it is not legal.

You might wish to investigate [Common Crawl](http://commoncrawl.org/), a website that has already crawled the entirety of the web. Check out their ToU section to check on the legality of it all.